# Create a rounded checkbox with boarder

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, drawable

This is how I create a rounded `checkbox` with boarder. But the boarder is in square shape,not circle.

**CheckBox**

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:button="@drawable/xml_button"
            android:background="@drawable/xml_background"/>
```

**xml_button**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#00FF00" />
            <size
                android:width="24dp"
                android:height="24dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#AAA" />
            <size
                android:width="24dp"
                android:height="24dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**xml_background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#CCC" />
    <padding
        android:left="34dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**Output**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, not going to post as an answer, as this is seriously day 2 on Android (currently iOS), but...

It seems your xml_background defines a radius of only 3dp (rather than, say...  half your height) and a stroke that is colored gray (CCC). I'd say you don't want that stroke on it at all.

just my thoughts,
-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this xml as background in your radio button .....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:color="#1E90FF" android:width="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#87CEEB"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**Note:-  I think your issue happened because of padding in round.xml**

> Output when unchecked ...

[image: e01]

> Output when checked ...

[image: gd]